# Journal entries for payment of tuition fees

Tags: accounting, double-entry

A student has total tuition fee of 8,000. The student paid 3,000 as a down payment and the journal entry is:

```
Cash 3,000
AR   5,000
     Tuition Fee  8,000
```

But what if the student will pay 3,500 for the next payment, what would be the journal entry? Is this correct?

```
Cash 3,500
AR   4,500
     Tuition Fee  8,000
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show it from the students point of view (albeit a student with an unusual level of precision in their budgeting). Otherwise it is off-topic in this stack.

Comment: @RupertMorrish Thank you for your response. Please check my updated question.

Comment: @RupertMorrish Can you please help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: If these are pre-payments/deposits prior to courses beginning, then a liability account for the school should be considered too.

Comment: @Luck What do you mean? Can you give example.

Comment: @Jearson This is beyond the scope of personal finance, but the school would record cash received and offset it to unearned revenue. Once the class/semester begins they can debit unearned revenue and credit tuition fees. I would suggest looking up "How to Report Deposits in Accrual Based Accounting" if you would like to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second journal entry is totally incorrect. It's simply

```
Cash 3,500
    Accounts Receivable 3,500
```

from the tuition fee recipient's point of view. From the student's point of view, the first payment is:

```
Tuition Fee 8,000
    Cash 3,000
    Accounts Payable 5,000
```

and the second payment is:

```
Accounts Payable 3,500
    Cash 3,500
```

Note by paying the second payment, the student is essentially converting the tuition fee recipient's Accounts Receivable into Cash. From the student's point of view, the student is converting cash into reduced Accounts Payable.

**Edit:** oh, and if your accounting program supports it, you might want to add this line to the journal entries:

```
    Tuition Fee 0,00
```

The idea is that it helps you remember to which account the Accounts Payable / Accounts Receivable transaction is related to. The Tuition Fee account is not part of the transaction otherwise.

Or, you could have hierarchical accounts `Accounts Receivable / Tuition Fee` (for tuition fee recipient) and `Accounts Payable / Tuition Fee` (for student).

Comment: Thank you so much for giving two point of views. But I am concern for the recipient's point of view, since I am doing a enrollment system with accounting.

Comment: Oaky I got your point. Thank you.